# Are questions on removing elementary and getting Windows back on on-topic?

Tags: discussion

If a question asking help to  **remove elementary** and getting (Microsoft) Windows back on, then is it on-topic or off-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, these are **off-topic**. You won't ask a Windows support (forum or commercial support by Microsoft) on how to install Linux on your computer either. Everyone is free to do whatever they want to do with their computer, but you cannot really expect help from a community dedicated to one operating system to help install another.

We are not a general computer support community. Installing another operating system (e.g. Windows) on your computer is not related to elementary OS at all. It's a question related to your computer. To your hardware.

There are a lot of dedicated Windows communities out there *and* there are a lot of articles about Windows installation (not that it's that complicated anyway) online. These will be able to support people in returning to Windows IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I am expressing my opinion as a member of this community</sub>

In my opinion, they should be **on-topic**,

**Why on-topic**:

- OP using **elementary**

**Why not off-topic**:

- Even if OP asking for keeping windows back on, treating windows as an application(to install) is legitimate. Because he has to create live usb in elementary and logically plenty of elementary related stuff will be in answers.

If still feel **off-topic**, I  request moderators, let there will be atleast "one" (exception) question (or let it be "**community wiki**" post ) of that type and close remaining questions as its duplicate.

Comment: Windows is not an application, period. We should not treat it like one either, because then we'll have to open the doors to other off-topic-but-fringe-on-topic questions as well due to fairness.

Comment: @RolandiXor I agree with you =). I am leaving this answer undelete so that it will be an example for future posts, thank you :)